# DRF : how to add user permissions to user detail api?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

So I am writing a `UserDetails` view as follows.

```
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthUserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

My Serializers are as follows.

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'codename')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True) 
    # permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
    # permissions = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Permission.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 
            'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 
            'date_joined', 'groups', 'user_permissions')
```

`groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)` gives me following.

```
"groups": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "B"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C"
        }
    ],
```

I expect the similar from `permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)` but I get the following error.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `permissions` on serializer `AuthUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'permissions'.
```

but instead, if add `user_permissions` to the fields directly without adding `related` reference it gives me all `id`s of permissions. I want to have `id`, `name`, `codename` also. And, Of course, `UserPermissions` model is not found. ;-(

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use source parameter on the Serializer.

```
class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True) 
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, source='user_permissions')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 
            'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 
            'date_joined', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'permissions')
```

Comment: This worked but it is not allowing me to select fields to be displayed. I had to use `__all__`.

Comment: Any idea why did it work without `source` in case of groups?

Comment: As groups is already m2m field on User model, you don't need set source parameter for this reason. If you change field name from permissions to user_permissions, you dont need source in the PermissionSerializer too.